# Finding the intersection between two integer arrays in postgres

Tags: sql, arrays, database, postgresql

In postgres [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html#INTARRAY-OP-TABLE)  I found that if I have two intarrays I can use the `&` operator to get the common elements between the two arrays(intersection), but this statement:

```
SELECT  ('{190,80}'::integer[]) & ('{190,80, 50}'::integer[])
```

raises this error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer[] & integer[]
LINE 1: SELECT  (('{190,80}'::integer[]) & ('{190,80, 50}'::integer[...
```

**I have postgresql version 13**

I am wondering why doesn't this work, and how can I fix the query or try another efficient alternative.

Comment: I'm curious if you try initializing your arrays outside the statement if that fixes your issue.

Comment: even if I use two columns from my table that are both already integer[] types it doesn't work,  so initializing before the statement won't work, I just posted this query because it's easier for everyone to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation you send is for an extension. To use it you have to run `CREATE EXTENSION intarray` on your database so that those commands work. This will load that extension to the database and from then on you will be able to use it on all queries on that database.

You can read more about extensions [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/external-extensions.html) and how to load them [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createextension.html)

Comment: thank you this worked for me.

Comment: when should I  run ```CREATE EXTENSION intarray``` each time I connect to the database, or running it once is enough

Comment: Extensions are created on the database so you only need to run it once I'll add the documentation on the answer

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

As answared by @NuLo, you should create the extension in your DB first:

```sql
create extension intarray;

select (array [190, 80] & array [190, 80, 50]);
```